# replacement for static variable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am developing an ASP.NET MVC 4 application. `userMenus` is a static variable that is loaded every time a user logs in.

```
public class MenuCL
{
    public static List<UserMenu> userMenus = new List<UserMenu>(); // the static variable
}

public class UserMenu
{
    public decimal MenuID { get; set; }
    public string MenuName { get; set; }
    public string Controller { get; set; }    
    public bool Permission { get; set; }
}
```

I use that static variable to check whether or not the logged in user has permission to a menu/controller in a custom authorize filter.

It works fine when a single user is logged in, but when two or more users are logged-in, it's all messed up, I mean the error page("you don't have access to this page") is displayed to a user that has permission to the menu/controller.

Only now I realized it's the static variable that is causing all the trouble, after I read this :

`The static variables will be shared between requests. Moreover they will be initialized when application starts, so if the AppDomain, thus application gets restarted, their values will be reinitialized.`

So I need a replacement for this static variable. Anyone has any suggestion?

Comment: Make it non-static? Why would it be static in the first place?

Comment: @nvoigt I use that static variable to check whether the user has permission to a controller/menu. So I need that `userMenus` to persist till the user logs out so I can check in my authorize filter whenever there's a request to a controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still use a static field which is a property that provides access to a session variable.

```
    public static List<UserMenu> UserMenus
    {
        set
        {
            Session["UserMenus"] = value;
        }
        get
        {
            return Session["UserMenus"] == null ? new List<UserMenu>() : (List<UserMenu>) Session["UserMenus"];
        }
    }
```

In order to get this working on a web farm which uses a session state server (or sql server), you need to put [[Serializable]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serializableattribute.aspx) attribute  on top of UserMenu.

I don't think, this way you need to modify your code very much.

Answer (score 1):

My question is, why do you want to use static variable? Do you want to share the values across the application? In this case you can better use `session`.

**Updated**

Assume `lst` as a non static `List` of `UserMenu`. Then you can use the following method to store it in session and get it bak whenever you want.

To store

`Session["usemenulist"] = lst`;

To get it back

```
try
{
 lst = (List<UserMenu>)Session["usemenulist"];
}
catch
{
}
```

**Note**
If you are getting the values from the database lo load it to the `List` for the first time, then you can query database to get it from the database whenever you want, instead of storing it in the session. (This is another option apart from `Session`, you may try this way also if you want.)

Comment: Yeah I need it across my application. How can I do it using session? Can I store the list `userMenus` in a session and retrieve it as a list when I need it?